# Selecting column from multi-index dataframe, to make for example an histogram

Tags: python, pandas, histogram, multi-index

This is the first time I work with multi-index dataframes. I have a dataframe which looks like this (tiny example):

```
import random
col3=[0,0,0,0,2,4,6,0,0,0,100,200,300,400]
col4=[0,0,0,0,4,6,8,0,0,0,200,900,400, 500]

d = {'Unit': [1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 6, 6, 6], 
 'Year': [2014, 2015, 2016, 2017, 2015, 2016, 2017, 2017, 2014, 2015, 2014, 2015, 2016, 2017], 'col3' : col3, 'col4' : col4 }
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df.groupby(['Unit', 'Year']).sum()

df = df.groupby(['Unit', 'Year']).sum()

df['mask'] = (df.groupby(level=0, group_keys=False)
                  .apply(lambda x: x.col3/x.col4.shift()))

df['mask'] = df['mask'].fillna(0)
```

Now I want to make a histogram for example from the values in the mask column, is this possible with out making a list first?

I did it like this:

```
values = [x for x in df['mask']]
plt.hist(values)
```

But i want to do it preferably without the intermediate list step.

Thank you,

Jen

Comment: Do you need `plt.hist(df['mask'])` ?

Comment: have you tried `df['mask'].plot(kind='hist')` ?

Answer (score 1):

List comprehension here is not necessary, only pass Series to `plot`:

```
plt.hist(df['mask'])
```

Or use [`Series.plot.hist`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.plot.hist.html):

```
df['mask'].plot.hist()
```

Comment: Thanx you for your answer. The second method of Series.plot.hist works for me. My dataset is extremely large and also contains -inf values. So via that method I could make a hist with the following: `df.A_4170_10_log[df['mask'] != -np.inf].plot.hist(bins = 50).` however the `plt.hist(df['mask'])` gives the following error: 
`ValueError: max must be larger than min in range parameter.` 
]). Do you by any change know what is wrong there?

Comment: @jenny - hmmm, not idea. if use `plt.hist(df.loc[df['mask'] != -np.inf, 'mask'])` not working?